# (PHP) Same procedures with different variables

Tags: php

I developed a template (HTML mixed with PHP) which contains a lot of reocurring procedures where just the variables and IDs change. Just like this:

```
    <?php if($_POST["finishtask1"])
{
    $project = \ProjectModel::findById($_POST["id"]);
    if($project->task1_member == $this->user["id"])
    {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $project->task1_end = $date->getTimestamp();
        $project->tstamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        $project -> save();
        // Redirect
        $newUrl = $this->replaceInsertTags('{{env::url}}') . "/";
        header('Location: '.$newUrl);
        exit();
    }
}?>

 <?php if($_POST["finishtask2"])
{
    $project = \ProjectModel::findById($_POST["id"]);
    if($project->task2_member == $this->user["id"])
    {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $project->task2_end = $date->getTimestamp();
        $project->tstamp = $date->getTimestamp();
        $project -> save();
        // Redirect
        $newUrl = $this->replaceInsertTags('{{env::url}}') . "/";
        header('Location: '.$newUrl);
        exit();
    }
}?>

....
```

I also have this in a mix of HTML and PHP. For example:

```
                                <?php if(!$project->task1_end && $project->task1_start && $this->user["id"] == $project->task1_member): ?>
                                <div class="fabutton finish">
                                    <form method="post">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="{{request_token}}" />
                                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $project->id ?>">
                                      <input type="submit" name="finishtask1" id="finishtask1" value="" onclick="return confirm('Question');" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
endif; ?>
<?php if(!$project->task2_end && $project->task2_start && $this->user["id"] == $project->task2_member): ?>
                                <div class="fabutton finish">
                                    <form method="post">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TOKEN" value="{{request_token}}" />
                                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $project->id ?>">
                                      <input type="submit" name="finishtask2" id="finishtask2" value="" onclick="return confirm('Question');" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
endif; ?>
```

Basically it is always the same, but just IDs and variables change. What would be the best practice here to don't repeat this over and over?

Comment: You can use dynamic attribute names, you could create a function which takes the variable attribute names (`function myFunc($taskMember, $taskEnd)`) and just uses them instead (`$project->{$taskEnd} = $date->getTimestamp();`).

Answer (score 1):

Put the code that repeats itself in a function.

The lines that differs are:

```
if($_POST["finishtask2"]) // the 2

if($project->task2_member == $this->user["id"]) // the 2

$project->task2_end = $date->getTimestamp(); // the 2
```

So you'll have to set a parameter in the function that holds the "serial number" (1,2..), lets call it: `$n`.

```
function myFunc($n) {
```

Now, lets see how we can implement that $n in the mentioned above commands:

```
if($_POST["finishtask2"]) --> if($_POST["finishtask" . $n])

if($project->task2_member ==  --> if($project->{'task'.{$n}.'_member'} ==

$project->task2_end --> $project->{'task'.{$n}.'_end'}
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you! How could I combine this with the HTML output? Use echo in the function?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use the echo command to print the HTML. echo 'Html goes here <div>test</div>'; Just make sure your quotes don't conflict.

Comment: Please see my answer above.